# How to edit a variable inside the model class in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model class as shown below:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #basket = {'list':['1']}
    search_list = {}
    shopping_basket = {}
```

I want to be able to add to the search_list dictionary within views. I'm currently doing this in views:

```
request.user.profile.search_list['results'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This adds it to every ones account though. How can i do it so its just one persons account?

Comment: your trying to access it on the `User` model, but your code show it on the `Profile` model. edit: see below answer

Answer (score 1):

For a start, `search_list` is an attribute of the Profile, not the User.

However **this will not do what you want**, since `search_list` and `shopping_basket` are class attributes and will therefore be shared by *all* Profiles. Do not do this.

To store arbitrary data, use the session.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: if i wanted to save permanently a dictionary to the user how would i do that? so they can log out and come back to the website on another day and still have the dictionary there

Comment: Then you would need to define an actual field on the model, probably some kind of JSON field; if you're using Postgres, there's one built-in to Django, otherwise you can use one of the many third-party libraries.

Answer (score -1):

To access `search_list` variable, you need to use correct instance name. Here's the example:

```
class Example:
    example_dict = {}


example = Example() # Here you are creating instance of the class Example
example.example_dict = {something} # Then you are accessing variable within the instance of the class
print(example.example_dict) # and printing it
```

Output of your program "'User' object has no attribute 'search_list'" literally shows that "User" is not instance of the Profile class, hence it does not have access to its variables.